# I want to install IIS in PowerShell 2.0 or 3.0

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have to create a script which installs the IIS, in PowerShell  2.0 or 3.0. Is it possible? I can't find commands such as get-webapplication or add-windowsfeature. I just need an idea, not the whole script.

Comment: It already exists. Look at `Chocolatey` https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll find add-windowsfeature in the servermanager module

```
import-module servermanager
add-windowsfeature web-Server
add-windowsfeature web-App-Dev
```

Comment: This only works on Server operating systems however.

Comment: Thank you! On Server 2008 works, of course. And in the end only on Server 2008 I needed to install IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey has this feature already, Usage: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/CommandsWindowsFeatures